# Backreference only replaces a pattern with one symbol

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace all `$postData[some_text]` with `$postData['some_text']`.

I tried looking for `(\$postData\[)+([a-zA-Z_+])+(\])` and replacing with `$postData['$2']` but it only replaces `some_text` with `'t'` i.e. the last letter of `some_text`. I don't get it, how do I keep the whole text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the quantifier inside the parentheses so you capture everything:

`\$postData\[+([a-zA-Z_+]+)\]`

replacement pattern:$1

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FZfhdJ/1/)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Haven't used regex in a while. Will accept when it lets me.